# NamedTuple Object mapping to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, object

So I have an Object that is validating a CSV file through a NamedTuple()...

```py
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import typing as T
import logging
from csv import DictReader
from collections import OrderedDict


class Validate(T.NamedTuple):

    field1: str
    field2: str
    field3: str


    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: dict):
        return cls(**{key: type_(row[key]) for key, type_ in cls._field_types.items()})

    @staticmethod
    def validate_csv(reader: DictReader) -> bool:
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            try:
                PCW.from_row(row)
            except Exception as ERROR_MESSAGE:
                logging.error(f'{ERROR_MESSAGE} -- row_number: {index + 1}')
                return False
        return True

def execute(csv_file):
    input_file = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
    return Validate.validate_csv(input_file)


execute("../test_csv.csv")
```

Excuse me if this is a design pattern, I'm fairly new to OOP programming.

This will work if we have a CSV file of the form:

`field1,field2,field3`

If all 3 fields are of the type  then it works - if any are of a different type then it will log. This is the intended behaviour.

However, what I would like to do is have some sort of method that runs just one row at a time, and every call it runs the next row through validation.

- since atm the whole CSV is validated, I want is to be able to pass just one row to `from_row` at a given time

ie:

```py
def csv_file(filepath: str):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
        for r in reader:
            yield r


for i in Validate.csv_file("../test_csv.csv"):
    Validate.validate_csv(i)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - does anyone know how I could get this working?

Comment: Instead of "yield r" in the csv_file function, just call "validate_csv(r)" instead.

Comment: `ERROR:root:string indices must be integers -- row_number: 1`, this is because `from_row` fails

Comment: Ah, I haven't adopted Typing yet, I don't really have an intuition on where you might go to fix that up.

Comment: Figured it out, feel free to check out solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all I needed to do was pass the whole reader to the `from_row` method, this will take each row and validate against the namedtuple :)

```py
(...)

 @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: dict):
        return cls(**{key: type_(row[key]) for key, type_ in cls._field_types.items()})


    @staticmethod
    def validate_csv(reader: dict) -> bool:
        try:
            PCW.from_row(reader)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"{e}")
            return False
        return True


def csv_file(filepath: str):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
        for r in reader:
            yield r


for i in csv_file("../test_csv.csv"):
    PCW.validate_csv(i)
```